# populate price section by selecting product in django formset

Tags: python, django, ajax

I have a Django formset with 6 input field. Whenever a user select a product for every row it will auto populate 3 fields named dp_price, tp_price and mrp. I have tried some but failed to do it by myself.

[image: my formset looks like this]

and my tried js file is

**add_purchase.js**

```
var send_data = {}

for(var i=0; i<10; i++){

    $(document).ready(function (prefix) {

         $('#id_form-' +prefix+ '-product').on('change', function () {
            console.log("On Product selected")
            let id = $(this).children('option:selected').val();
            console.log(id);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'product-info',
                data: {
                  'pk': id
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $("#id_form-"+prefix+"-dp_price").val(data.dp_price);
                    $("#id_form-"+prefix+"-tp_price").val(data.tp_price);
                    $("#id_form-"+prefix+"-mrp").val(data.mrp_price);
                }
            });
        })(i);
    });
}
```

**forms.py**

```
PurchaseChildFormset = modelformset_factory(

    PurchaseChild,

    form=PurchaseChildFormCreateForm,
    extra=1,
    widgets={
        'product': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', }),
        'dp_price': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', }),
        'tp_price': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', }),
        'mrp': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', }),
        'qty': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'line_total': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    },
)
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required

def product_info(request):

    print("product_info called")

    id = request.GET.get('pk', None)

    product = Product.objects.get(pk=id)

    print(id)

    data = {
        'name': product.name,
        'dp_price': product.dp_price,
        'tp_price': product.tp_price,
        'mrp_price': product.mrp_price,
    }
    print(data)
    # print(data)
    return JsonResponse(data, status=200)
```

Comment: first you couls use `print()` and `console.log()` to see what you get - and you could show it in question (not in comment). Second: JavaScript sends data to url `product-info` but you didn't show `view` for this url (function in file `views.py`). This function has to get data from JavaScript/AJAX and send back information which AJAX will use to fill form in browser.

Comment: views.py

@login_required

def product_info(request):

    print("product_info called")
    id = request.GET.get('pk', None)
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=id)
    print(id)
    data = {
        # 'id': customer.customer_address,
        # 'phone': customer.phone,
        'name': product.name,
        'dp_price': product.dp_price,
        'tp_price': product.tp_price,
        'mrp_price': product.mrp_price,
    }
    print(data)
    # print(data)
    return JsonResponse(data, status=200)

Comment: I added the views.py to the main question. please check

Comment: do you get any error messages in console and/or in browser? Did you check in DevToolsin browser if there are some error messages for `JavaScript`?

Comment: No error message

Comment: I have no idea what else to do. I can't run it to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

To render this in frontend on native templates django,  you only do will can do this: Ex Javascript